# ITK update function

Tags: c++, itk

I'm trying to deform a sphere and then display it on vtk.

I'm having trouble with Update() function becuase I'm not sure if I have to use it after every filter I create.

```
typedef itk::TriangleMeshToSimplexMeshFilter< TMesh, TSimplex > TConvert;
typedef itk::SimplexMeshToTriangleMeshFilter< TSimplex, TMesh > TReverseConvert;
typedef itk::DeformableSimplexMesh3DBalloonForceFilter< TSimplex, TSimplex > TDeform;

TConvert::Pointer convertSimplex = TConvert::New();
convertSimplex->SetInput(sphere->GetOutput());
//If I use Update the next line then I'm having errors at execution
convertSimplex->Update();

TDeform::Pointer balloon = TDeform::New();
balloon->SetInput(convertSimplex->GetOutput());
//....Some deform values i.e. alpha and beta
balloon->SetRigidity(0);
balloon->Update(); //Again the same problem

TReverseConvert::Pointer reverse = TReverseConvert::New();
reverse->SetInput(ballon->GetOutputPort());
reverse->Update();
```

Do I have to do it just at the end of all filters? What if I add more and more filters and I don't know the order of them? (Suppose that the order depends on user actions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to call `Update()` on the last filter in your pipeline. The rest of this answer is the explanation.

ITK uses a pipeline execution framework for filters. Assume we have three filters that are connected sequentially like the following:

input --> |filter1| --> |filter2| --> |filter3| --> output

If you call `Update()` on filter3, ITK starts from filter3 and checks if the input(s) to each filter have changed. If they have, ITK calls update on them in turn. See slide 5 of this [link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~galeotti/methods_course/ITK_Pipeline.pdf).